# C# Find empty cells and write them inside with ClosedXml

Tags: c#, excel, closedxml

I have this problem, I have installed ClosedXml:

I have an Excel file already created and populated, now I should find the blank line below the already populated one and write some data

Example:

[A, 1] = name;
[B, 1] = surname;

the next line will be empty and I will pass some variables to populate the cells going to the right.

```
OpenFileDialog FileExcel = new OpenFileDialog();

        if (FileExcel.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                var sr = new StreamReader(FileExcel.FileName);
            }
            catch (SecurityException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"Security error.\n\nError message: {ex.Message}\n\n" +
                $"Details:\n\n{ex.StackTrace}");
            }
        }


using (var excelWorkbook = new XLWorkbook(FileExcel.FileName))
        {
            var nonEmptyDataRows = excelWorkbook.Worksheet(Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.SelectedItem)).RowsUsed();

            foreach (var dataRow in nonEmptyDataRows)
            {
                //for row number check
                if (dataRow.RowNumber() >= 1 && dataRow.RowNumber() <= 100)
                {

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: you can check if the cell is empty with  `if(String.IsNullOrEmpty( IsNull(Cell.Value))`

Comment: @styx IsNull does not exist in the current context erroe code CS0103 and 
CS0117 Cell does not contain a definition for "Value"

Answer (score 3):

Use `row.Cells(false)` instead of `row.Cells()`. It does not skip over unused cells. Then you can simply check of `cell.Value()` is empty

Answer (score 2):

you can do something like that

```
  int lastrow = worksheet.LastRowUsed().RowNumber(); 
  var rows = worksheet.Rows(1, lastrow);
  foreach (IXLRow  row in rows)
  {
      foreach (IXLCell cell in row.Cells())
      {                
          if (cell.IsEmpty())
          {
                //do something
          }

       }
   }
```

Comment: error CS1061 does not contain a definition of LastRowUsed, 
even if I put the name of the variable on my sheet

Comment: try  `var totalRows = worksheet.RowsUsed().Count();`

Comment: Then the cycle sees the lines used, but not the ones after they are empty. So in the row.IsEmpty format it never enters.

Example:
A1: full;
A2: full;
A3: empty

the cycle sees up to the A2.

Comment: @Mrpit fixed my answer I was looking for an empty row, not an empty cell

Comment: thanks, but I solved it like this:

IXLWorksheet Worksheet2 = excelWorkbook.Worksheet (Convert.ToInt32 (Page Number));
                    IXLCell CellForNewData = Worksheet2.Cell (lastrow + 1, 1);